# How can I take a single unmoving value from a variable that is changing in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity3D and I have an integer variable that changes by one every time the user presses a button. I need to make it so that the user can not press a second button unless the integer value changed by 10 from the time that they pressed the first button.

This is the code that I have tried:

```
if (ImprovedRelations == true)
    {
        if(TurnsNow == TurnsNow + 10)
        {
            relationNumber.LithuaniaREL += 50;
            IncreasedPopularity = true;
        }
```

I believe that the reason it did not work was because earlier on, I made this following line of code:

```
TurnsNow = Turns.TurnNumber;
```

which made the 'TurnsNow' variable change with the 'TurnsNumber' integer.
How would I be able to make the 'TurnsNow' variable unchanging so that I can keep track of what the variable was when I clicked that button but not further.

Comment: You need to remember the old value like `int TurnsWhenButtonWasPressed;` and then compare to that

Comment: or use two counting variables. The second one would be reset to 0 when the count to 10 has to begin.

Comment: Could you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what exactly you are trying to do?